# Making Preline for Tailwind work in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm looking to setup preline in nuxt 3. I've followed their Nuxt 2 guide to no avail. Here's my code currently, it looks like nuxt isn't even rendering the script?

`npm i preline`

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
  head: {
    script: [
        {
          src: '~/node_modules/preline/dist/preline.js',
          body: true,
          defer: true
        }
    ]
  },
```

And the tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    '~/node_modules/preline/dist/preline.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('preline/plugin'),
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder inside `node_modules/preline` and paste it inside the public folder.
After change

```
src: '~/node_modules/preline/dist/preline.js'
```

to

```
src: '/preline/dist/preline.js',
```

Comment: How about when the code is updated? This doesn't seem like a good way to use a npm package.